# why is target encoder giving these results?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categories, feature-engineering

i am using target encoder e.g.:

```
preprocess = make_column_transformer(
    (SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value = 0),numeric_cols),
    (ce.TargetEncoder(),['country'])
    )

pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocess,XGBClassifier())

# Initialize Grid Search Modelg
clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline,param_grid = param_grid,scoring = 'roc_auc',
                                 verbose= 1,iid= True,
                                     refit = True,cv  = 3)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

model_best =clf.best_estimator_
```

then to see what the output dataframe looks like:

```
pd.DataFrame(model_best[0].fit_transform(X_train,y_train),columns =feature_names  )
```

i get for country: germany = 0.161239, france = 0.096425 which is exactly same as results from this:

```
check1 = pd.concat([X_train['country'], y_train,], axis=1)

check1.groupby(['country']).mean()
```

however when i do this:

```
pd.DataFrame(model_best[0].fit_transform(X_test,y_test),columns =feature_names )
```

the replaced probabilities in country column are different to ones from train. shouldn't they be the same as the values from the train set?? e.g. i get germany =   0.162752 and
FR  0.079511.

i thought that in MTE the test set is using info from the training set?? as is outlined here: https://www.kaggle.com/ogrellier/python-target-encoding-for-categorical-features

Comment: You should not be refitting the target encoder in the last line (nor really in the last line of your first codeblock).  Try instead with `...model_best[0].transform(X_test, ...`.  What's MTE?

Comment: even doing that though gives the mean from the test not train, mte is mean target enoding

Comment: Odd.  Can you provide a MWE then, please?